# What is the point of app.set('views', '/public') if you have app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));?

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, what is the point of setting `views`

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
```

when you have

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Don't they accomplish the same thing? Does one have features/advantages that the other doesn't have?

Comment: You can have dynamic components on views. Static files are css, javascript and image files which don't change at all.

Comment: By dynamic you mean like ejs?

Comment: Yes, like ejs or any other templating engines.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't they accomplish the same thing?" They don't.

With `app.set('views', …)` you're setting the Express's [app setting](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.settings.table) which is

> A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.

It's used by `.render()` function to look up views, which are usually dynamic like Jade.

With [`app.use(express.static(…))`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) you're defining a middleware whose only purpose is to serve static files like JS/CSS.

So essentially they're both fundamentally different things.

Comment: Hmmm... so I have an Angular app and it is already dynamic in its own way. It's all in the folder app. Should I just point the `static` property to my Angular folder?

Comment: Yes, and actually dynamic here in Express's context means something else, like one that uses a templating language like Jade to generate HTML (the view). I'm guessing your Angular app consists only of HTML files and client-side JavaScript files, which would just be "static" files in Express's context.